# Normalize energy of two audio signals

Tags: matlab, audio, normalization, envelope

I have different audio signals and I want to ensure that all of them have the same energy. The goal is that they sound equal (same volume) when I play them. 
I tried the following method (explained above) but when I play them they sound different. Also, if I compute the energy after the normalization that I apply, it is different. What am I doing wrong?

What I do is:
1) calculate the energy for each audio signal using the envelope with the hilbert transform,

```
% Calculate the envelope
envelope = abs(hilbert(wave));

% Calculate the energy in the sound
energyInSound=sum(envelope.^2)
```

2) ensure they have the same energy,

```
for channel=1:2
        regWave(:,channel) =  1000.* wave(:,channel)./energyInSound(channel);
end
```

Comment: You should normalize based on _power_, not energy (use `mean` instead of `sum`). Otherwise a longer signal will have more energy and will be "normalized" to a lower volume. Also, note that power doesn't reflect perceived power exactly, so it will only be approximate. For example, the human auditory system is less sensitive to very low or high frequencies. a 1-kHz tone will sound louder than a 100-Hz tone with the same power

Comment: @LuisMendo - I'd +10 that comment if I could.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! I think you too are an amateur musician (but I don't remember where I saw that)  :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - Most likely LinkedIn :D lol.  Yes you are correct... and correct here too on all accounts.

Comment: @rayryeng Oh I see. I play guitar too!

Comment: @LuisMendo - Very nice :) I haven't picked it up in a while.... I should soon.... too busy answering SO questions :D

Comment: @LuisMendo All my audio signals have the same length so that wont be a problem. I tried with mean(envelope.^2)) and that distort my sound, actually it changes completely. Perhaps I am not doing correctly?

Comment: If they are fixed-length signal, `mean(envelope.^2)` and `sum(envelope.^2)` should do the same (up to a constant)

Answer (score 0):

What I did (with two signals of the same length) was multiplying the signal with the biggest energy by sqrt(energyRatio) and the other .*energyRatio.

```
tempSig1 = sig1.*energyRatio;
tempSig2 = sig2.*sqrt(energyRatio);
```

This changes the energy values of the signals to be equal.